# Push to an array created inside a function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays

I want to create a temporary array that is returned from a function. I declare it in the function and use the `memory` tag but I am unable to push to it.

```
function getAllLandForSale() external returns(uint256[]){

        uint[] memory propertiesForSaleArray;

        // Get the total number of properties created
        uint256 totalNumberOfProperties = baseContract.getLandArrayLength();

        for(uint i = 0; i < totalNumberOfProperties; ++i) {

           address currentOwner = baseContract.getLandOwner(i);

           if(currentOwner == address(0)){

               propertiesForSaleArray.push(i);

           }

        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you can still do `propertiesForSaleArray[i] = i;`

Comment: If I do that will there be gaps in the returned array where the address is not 0 for example array[value,empty,empty,value,value]? I was looking for something like [value,value,value] etc.

Comment: yes, but you can avoid them by adding simple counter which will increase its own value only when new element is added to the array.

Comment: Sorry you have lost me with that bit of advice, not sure what you mean by a counter will increase its own value.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing what I tried to say in comment section below the question:

```
uint c = 0; // counter

for(uint i = 0; i < totalNumberOfProperties; ++i) {

   address currentOwner = baseContract.getLandOwner(i);

   if(currentOwner == address(0)){

      propertiesForSaleArray[c] = i;

      c = c + 1;

      // this will only add propeties for sale to your array, without the gaps
   }
}
```